# How to get requested user in clean function in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Well i want to get requested user in clean function of django forms but i'm unable to do that. I'm trying to get that by simply saying **self.request.user** , it works in views but not working in forms.py, anybody have an idea how to get requested user in djnago forms ?

forms.py

```
class KycModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = KycModel
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(KycModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
        print(user)
```

views.py

```
class KycFormCreateView(CreateView):
    
    form_class = KycModelForm
    model = KycModel
    template_name = "accounts/kyc/new_kyc.html"
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_kyc = form.save(commit=False)
        user_kyc.owner = self.request.user 
        user_kyc.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never construct a form with a request in the first place. You should pass this with:

```
class KycFormCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = KycModelForm
    model = KycModel
    template_name = 'accounts/kyc/new_kyc.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user_kyc = form.save(commit=False)
        user_kyc.owner = self.request.user 
        user_kyc.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In the `clean` function, you do *not* need to query for a user `self.request.user` *is* a user object, so you can work with `self.request.user` *directly*:

```
class KycModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = KycModel
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(KycModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        user = self.request.user
        print(user)
        return cleaned_data
```