# Django forms passing request via get_form_kwargs fails to give form access to self.request.user

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

## Goal

I need to make the user accessible to a form for validation (i.e., through `self.request.user`)

## Approach Taken

I use the `get_form_kwargs()` function in my view to make the request available to my form (as suggested here: [Very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571393/11482075)).

## Problem

Despite following the steps outlined in the StackOverflow answer linked above, I'm getting the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`

### Code

#### views.py

```
class MemberDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    """View class for member profile page"""
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs,)
        context['form'] = JoinCommunityForm()
        return context
    
class JoinCommunityFormView(FormView):
    """View class for join code for users to join communities"""
    form_class = JoinCommunityForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """posts the request to join community only if user is logged in"""
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
class MemberDashboardView(View):
    """View class to bring together the MemberDetailView and the JoinCommunityFormView"""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = MemberDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = JoinCommunityFormView.as_view()
        form = JoinCommunityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
```

#### forms.py

*Line where error is being raised is **`user=self.request.user`** *

```
from communities.models import Community, UserRoleWithinCommunity

class JoinCommunityForm(forms.Form):
    pin = forms.RegexField(
                           '^[A-HJ-NP-Z1-9]$',
                           max_length=6, 
                           label='',
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               'oninput': 'this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()'
                                                        }
                                                  )
                           )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(JoinCommunityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pin = self.cleaned_data['pin']
        test_join_code = f'{pin}'
        if Community.objects.filter(join_code=test_join_code).exists():
            # Make sure user is not already a member of the community
            communityToJoin = Community.objects.get(join_code=test_join_code)
            if UserRoleWithinCommunity.objects.filter(
                community=communityToJoin,
                user=self.request.user
            ).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("You're already a member 
                                             of that Community")
            else:
                return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Join code is incorrect")
```

## Edit 1:

I've tried the approach suggested by Willem but am still butting up against the same error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`, which is tracing back to that one line in my form where I need to access the user through `self.request.user`.

All `forms.py` code remains the exact same as above. My `views.py` code has changed as follows (I now only have a single view rather than two views (form view and detail view) that feed into another view):

#### views.py

```
# all necessary import statements

class MemberDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin,
        generic.DetailView, ProcessFormView
    ):
    """View class for member profile page"""
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'
    form_class = JoinCommunityForm
    success_url = '#communities-card'
    template_name = 'home/terpuser_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(
            **kwargs,
            demo=get_object_or_404(Scenario.objects, scenario_id='demo'),
            today=date.today(),
        )
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # this is where I put my code to create a new Community 
        # membership object
        return super().form_valid(self, form)
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('member/<slug:slug>/', views.MemberDetailView.as_view(), name='member-detail')
]
```

#### error message

- Request Method:   POST
- Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/member/tron/
- Django Version:   4.1.5
- Exception Type:   AttributeError
- Exception Value:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'
- Exception Location:   ../projDir/home/forms.py, line 53, in clean
- Raised during:    home.views.MemberDetailView
- Python Executable:    ../projDir/django-terp-venv/bin/python
- Python Version:   3.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I needed to get the current user (not just the `request`) using the form class's `__init__` method. Below is the `views.py` and `forms.py` code that ended up working:

### views.py

```
# all necessary import statements

class MemberDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin,
        generic.DetailView, ProcessFormView
    ):
    """View class for member profile page"""
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'
    form_class = JoinCommunityForm
    success_url = '#communities-card'
    template_name = 'home/terpuser_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(
            **kwargs,
            demo=get_object_or_404(Scenario.objects, scenario_id='demo'),
            today=date.today(),
        )
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # this is where I put my code to create a new Community membership object
        return super().form_valid(self, form)
```

### forms.py

The line that ended up solving my problems is in the form class's `__init__` method: `self.user = self.request.user`. Then, I call `self.user` in the form class's `clean` method rather than `self.request.user`

```
from communities.models import Community, UserRoleWithinCommunity

class JoinCommunityForm(forms.Form):
    pin = forms.RegexField(
                           '^[A-HJ-NP-Z1-9]$',
                           max_length=6, 
                           label='',
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               'oninput': 'this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()'
                                                        }
                                                  )
                           )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None) # instantiate request kwarg as Willem suggests
        self.user = self.request.user # get user, this was key to resolving error
        super(JoinCommunityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pin = self.cleaned_data['pin']
        test_join_code = f'{pin}'
        if Community.objects.filter(join_code=test_join_code).exists():
            # Make sure user is not already a member of the community
            communityToJoin = Community.objects.get(join_code=test_join_code)
            if UserRoleWithinCommunity.objects.filter(
                community=communityToJoin,
                user=self.user # here I call self.user instead of self.request.user
            ).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("You're already a member 
                                             of that Community")
            else:
                return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Join code is incorrect")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this did not work is because you constructed the form with `JoinCommunityForm(request.POST)`, whereas Django's `FormMixin` will call `get_form_kwargs()` and then pass these to the form, as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/21e686471598d6c755d93a570de20dc00d8d27f6/django/views/generic/edit.py#L33-L37):

> ```
> def get_form(self, form_class=None):
>     """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
>     if form_class is None:
>         form_class = self.get_form_class()
>     return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
> ```

In your view you can however easily handle this with:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin, ProcessFormView


class MemberDetailView(
    LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, generic.DetailView, ProcessFormView
):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user'
    form_class = JoinCommunityForm
    template_name = '…'  # template used in MemberDetailView

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do something when the form is valid
        return super().form_valid(self, form)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this leads to the exact same error message: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: @DevinGilbert: I forgot to add the `get_form_kwargs` method :)